# RVM: List all gems in current gemset ignoring global & default

Tags: rubygems, rvm, gemset

Looking for something like `gem list` within an RVM gemset but to have it ignore gems in the **global** and **default** gemsets so I can see, easily, exactly what gems are in the active gemset (and *only* the active gemset).

Answer (score 68, accepted):

for global:

```
rvm @global do gem list
```

for other gemsets:

```
GEM_PATH=$GEM_HOME gem list
```

---

`@global` is a gemset that all other gemsets inherit for given ruby, it does not inherit for m itself so it's safe to select it and run `gem list` in it's context.

For all other gemsets you can use the fact that `gem list` displays gems from all paths available in `GEM_HOME` and `GEM_PATH`, resetting `GEM_PATH` to be equal `GEM_HOME` will make only one path available - the one from `GEM_HOME` so `gem list` will only show gems in the selected gemset, ignoring all other gemsets (at this time the `@global`, but RVM 2.0 will support multiple gemsets inheritance).

Comment: but if you re-assign `GEM_PATH` for this then won't you have to set it back afterwards?!?

Comment: no, because it's part of one command, this assignment takes effect only for this command, you could prefix it all with `env` just to be sure: `env GEM_PATH=$GEM_HOME gem list`

Answer (score 28):

Simplest way to do it is to use bash command which show list of directories in your current gemset directory

```
$ ls `rvm gemdir`/gems
```

Comment: works! what's going on there? I'm not familiar with `\`` on the command line.

Comment: `ls` just lists directory content taking your current gemset dir as argument. Gemset dir is taken from `rvm gemdir` command with appended `/gems` (it's the place where all gem folders live). 8)

Comment: ya familiar with `ls`, etc. but hadn't seen the use of `\`` to enclose a *variable?* or *expression?* before...

Comment: Backticks help to run enclosed command _before_ running main. And give result of _backticked?_ command to main.

Answer (score 4):

First, whenever any other gemset is selected, the default (no-name) gemset's contents become invisible.

As you know, effectively the @global gemset is [included](https://rvm.io/gemsets/global/) in all other gemsets for the currently selected Ruby normally.

However, to see the contents of a gemset, excluding the @global gemset, first do `rvm use 2.0.0@some-gemset --ignore-gemsets` (or [similar](https://rvm.io/gemsets/ignoring/) for other Rubies) then `gem list`.

Similarly to see the contents of the @global gemset, first do `rvm use 2.0.0@global` then `gem list`.

And similarly to see the contents of the default gemset, do `rvm use 2.0.0 --ignore-gemsets` then `gem list`.

BTW, you can select a gemset to be the (so-called) [default](https://rvm.io/gemsets/using/) for new (non-login) shells (and I always do so in `.bash_profile`, etc. separately for each Ruby interpreter) but that is another kind of default gemset, not the (unnamed) default gemset above.

Comment: Thanks. The "problem" I'm trying to solve is related to `gem update`/`bundle update`. I'd like it, when run, to only update gems within the gemset that they currently reside. I have some gems in `global` and others in `some-gemset`. When I run `gem update` from `some-gemset` it updates ALL gems (incl. `global`) into `some-gemset`. What I do now, every time I update, is switch to `global` first and `gem update` THEN switch to `some-gemset`. Workable but it gets squirrely when you add Gemfiles and Bundler to the mix...

Comment: Quicker is `(rvm use 2.0.0@some-gemset --ignore-gemsets; gem update)`. For Bundler, it's `(rvm use 2.0.0@some-gemset --ignore-gemsets; bundle update)`. But if you want Bundler to install some (not all) new gems into @global, that's difficult.

Comment: Thank you! :) this solves my issue! spent almost 5 hours on this already.